# Symfony - Multiple sfWidgetFormPropelChoice filter- How to select all by default?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel, symfony-forms

I'm using a `sfWidgetFormPropelChoice` widget in a filter, with the multiple select option turned on.

Is there an easy way to have **ALL** of the options selected by default?

I know I can use set default to select specific options, but I want them all added,
even as the table grows.

```
$this->setDefault('field', array(1,2,3,4,5));
```

Comment: I think if you add a HTML option of `'checked' => 'checked'` it will select everything.  I'm not in front of my IDE to check though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not giving all values from the table as a default array ? Something like (I will take a default table called `Article`):

```
// in your model
class ArticleQuery extends BaseArticleQuery
{
  static public function getDefaultsValue()
  {
    $articles = self::create()
      ->setFormatter('PropelArrayFormatter')
      ->find();

    $default = array();
    foreach($articles as $article)
    {
      $default[] = $article['Id'];
    }

    return $default;
  }
```

And then, in your setDefault:

```
$this->setDefault('field', ArticleQuery::getDefaultsValue());
```